# @azure/identity credentials.getToken('openid') returns null instead of token for DefaultAzureCredential() with Environment variables configed?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, service-principal

I'm trying to retrieve some secrets from Azure's keyvault but I cannot seem to authenticate using @azure/identity module.

Versions:

```
"@azure/identity": "^1.0.0-preview.6",
"@azure/keyvault-secrets": "^4.0.0-preview.9",
```

When I try to get the token:

```
import { KeyVaultSecret, SecretClient } from '@azure/keyvault-secrets';
import { EnvironmentCredential } from '@azure/identity';

export const GetSecret = async (key: string): Promise<string> => {
    try {
        const credential: EnvironmentCredential = new EnvironmentCredential();
        const token = await credential.getToken('openid');
        console.log(token);
        console.log('CREDENTIAL: ', credential);
        console.log('CLIENT SECRET', process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET);
        console.log('CLIENT ID', process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID);
        return 'test'
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error getting secret from Azure Vault', err);
    }
};
```

Console result:

```
 CREDENTIAL:  DefaultAzureCredential {
[10/28/2019 2:39:27 PM]   _sources:
[10/28/2019 2:39:27 PM]    [ EnvironmentCredential { _credential: undefined },
[10/28/2019 2:39:27 PM]      ManagedIdentityCredential {
[10/28/2019 2:39:27 PM]        isEndpointUnavailable: null,
[10/28/2019 2:39:27 PM]        identityClient: [IdentityClient] } ] }
```

Comment: I think you need to ask for a token for resource `https://vault.azure.net` or scope `https://vault.azure.net/.default`, not openid

Comment: hi @juunas -- thanks for replying -- I've tried both of those and still getting only nulls :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the appropriate environment variables for CLIENT_SECRET and CLIENT_ID?

The `EnvironmentCredential()` class expects you to have these variables configured.  Typically, you would create a service principal (SP) for your application to use.  You can then apply RBAC to this service principal, for example, by assigning the Reader role, or KeyVault Contributor role to the SP.

If you don't want to go this route, take a look at SAS tokens instead:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys

Comment: If you read right there in my try {} catch {} block you can see I'm already logging on the console the appropriate credentials as in the documentation to confirm that they are set and available. I also don't need a storage key as I'm trying to access the keyvault.

Comment: Yes apologies I overlooked that.  And your logger is logging 2 values for the variables that look like GUIDs?